# Getting a href source within the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am loading a url using a iframe and when a user click on any link within the iframe, i am trying to get that href source and append to a url and redirect it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.google.com" >Google</a><br/>

<iframe src="http://example.com" width="100%" height="700px"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Using below javascript code(found on stack overflow), it is redirecting the links on web page(Ex; google link in the page) but its not redirecting the links in the iframe.

```
    $('a').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var href = $(this).attr('href')
      window.location='http://someurlhere?link=' + href;
    });
```

How to do get the link source from the Iframe and append it to a url and redirect it?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible as the content of the iframe is coming from a third-party domain. If you own both domains then you could potentially use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), although I'd argue there's far better ways to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do without resorting to that

Comment: Its a third party domain. what is the best way to get what i am trying? is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Then no, there's nothing at all you can do. This behaviour is blocked for security reasons. Imagine how easy it would be to spoof/phish if you could actually do what you're asking.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, but i am trying to just show the content of the page. They should bring some changes (Allowing to show content etc.)

Comment: It's never going to happen. It would be far too easy to exploit.